# Applying Patches to Drupal modules - How to deal with error messages?

Tags: 7, drush, version-control

I am trying to apply patch #110 from here in [Drupal 7 - ViewsCalc](https://www.drupal.org/node/140665).

I am following the instructions on this page: [Applying patches on Mac OS X](https://www.drupal.org/node/60818)

When following the instructions, I get this error message:

```
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/theme.inc b/theme.inc
|index 57d61ed..7db435b 100644
|--- a/theme.inc
|+++ b/theme.inc
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

What should I do?

I've tried giving it the path to the `theme.inc` file.  When I do this, it displays the following:

```
No such file or directory
Skip this patch? [y]
```

As a work around, I have installed [Drush Issue Queue Commands](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_iq) and I have applied the following command in Drush:
`drush iq-apply-patch 140665-#110`

When I use this Drush command, I get the following error message:

```
Drush iq-apply-patch 140665-1: downloading patchfile                 [ok]
views_calc_grouping_140665-114.patch for project views_calc
Could not apply the patch with either -Np0 or -Np1; perhaps the patch[error]
was rolled for a different version of the project.
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I'm not sure if this is a valid question, as it deals with patching. However, it also deals with topics such as Drush so I believe it is on topic. If it is off topic, please could you direct me to the correct place to post it.

Comment: Did you try to patch the production version (7.x-1.1) or the development version (7.x-1.x-dev). The patch is built against the development version (you can see that in the right top issue summary). But since the patch is over a year old now, it might be that it no longer applies against the dev as well.

Comment: @Neograph734 I've tried both dev and non dev versions. Is there a way to access the dev version from when the patch was made?

Comment: Since this is git you could try to clone the repository (see the `version control` section under the title of the module project page) and revert some of the changes locally. So it is possible yes (though that IS off topic here). Also be careful as it can introduce security vulnerabilities. I'd recommend to start over again first. Remove all files, download the dev version and try one way to apply the patch. If it fails, start over again and try another way. (If a patch is applied partially all other attempts to patch it will fail.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I worked this out!

When I was applying the patch, I placed the patch file in the root module directory. But it actually has to go inside in the directory of the actual module. Whoops!

E.g.

The patch goes inside of `sites>all>modules>views_calc`
and not inside of `sites>all>modules`.